# Asynchronous Loop mixing meta item

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape the following website:

https://institucional.xpi.com.br/sobre-a-xp/encontre-um-escritorio/

I have a dropdown list to select a state, from that state it gives me a dropdown list from the cities available.

After submitting, I get the list of all offices (address,e-mail,phone number) for that city.

With this code, I'm not getting all the results and also I'm getting repeated city names, it looks like the meta item is mixing from one loop with the other.
I tried to debug, but here is what happens:

I start the first parse function, when I enter the loop for each state, I get the first state ("AC") when I arrive at the yield line, I expected it to go to the parseStates function but it starts the loop again.

The thing is, it doesn't do the whole loop, it loops through the first five states, then it jumps the the parseStates function.

```
def parse(self, response):

    statesList = ["AC","AL","AM","BA","CE","DF","ES","GO","MA","MG","MS","MT","PA","PB","PE","PR","RJ","RN","RO","RS","SC","SE","SP"]

    for state in statesList:
        linkState = 'https://institucional.xpi.com.br/api/Escritorios/FilialListarCidadesV2?vSiglaEstado=' + state
        location = LocationItem()
        location['state']=state

        yield scrapy.Request(url=linkState, callback=self.parseStates, meta={'item':location})

def parseStates(self,response):
        location=response.meta['item']

        root = ET.fromstring(response.body)
        cityList = [city.text for city in root.iter('{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XP.Portal.Entities}Nome')]

        for city in cityList:
            location['city']=city
            state = location['state']

            linkCity = 'https://institucional.xpi.com.br/api/Escritorios/FilialListarPorEstadoCidadeV2?vSiglaEstado=' + state + '&vNomeCidade='+city.replace(' ','%20')
            yield scrapy.Request(url=linkCity, callback=self.parseCities,meta={'item':location})

def parseCities(self,response):
        location = response.meta['item']
        state = location['state']
        city = location['city']

        root = ET.fromstring(response.body)

        mailList = [elem.text for elem in root.iter('{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XP.Portal.Entities}EmailPadronizadoSocioResponsavel')]
        companyList = [elem.text for elem in root.iter('{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XP.Portal.Entities}RazaoSocial')]
        contactList = [elem.text for elem in root.iter('{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XP.Portal.Entities}SocioResponsavel')]
        telList = [elem.text for elem in root.iter('{http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XP.Portal.Entities}Telefone')]

        for i in range(len(mailList)):
            write(state,city,companyList[i],contactList[i],mailList[i],telList[i])
```

Comment: Isn't supposed to see repeated cities, since there is more than one venue per city?

Comment: Yes, but for all entries of the same state it's repeating the city name.
For ex.
State A has City 1 with 3 entries and City 2 with 6 entries.
In the output I'm finding State A with only City 2 but with 7 entries. (Not only the entries from city 2 but also not all the entries)